# How to obtain dynamic radio array values

Tags: php, arrays

I just cannot figure this one out. 
In PHP I created dynamic radio buttons, that populate based on form data collected, from an associated array. For example, the associated array and values are:

Array listing code:

```
foreach($_SESSION['items'] as $key=>$value)
{
echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />'; 
}
```

## Array echo results:

The value of $_SESSION['0'] is 'Ralph'

The value of $_SESSION['1'] is 'Cindy'

The value of $_SESSION['2'] is 'Katie'

Next I take the array values to create a radio button array, to ask for user comparisons, as below (using double loop works well):

```
<form name="ranking_submit" action="" method="post">
<?php
echo "<br>";
// compare each array item with each other - one time
$radiocounta = 40;
$radiocountb = 0;
$radiocountc = 80;

$sizeZ=count($_SESSION['items']);
echo "<table>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $sizeZ-1; $i++) 
{
for ($j = $i+1; $j < $sizeZ; $j++) 
{
$radiocounta += 1;
$radiocountc += 1;
$radiocountb += 1;
echo "<tr><td class='rright ratecell'><div class='big ccenter'>"."<input id='".$radiocounta . "' type='radio' required='required' name='". $radiocountb ."' value= '".$_SESSION['items'][$i]."' />"."<label for='".$radiocounta. "' title='".$_SESSION['items'][$i]."'>".$_SESSION['items'][$i]."</label></div></td><td class='ccenter'>"." vs "."</td><td class='ratecell'><div class='big ccenter'>"."<input id='".$radiocountc . "' type='radio' name='". $radiocountb ."' value= '".$_SESSION['items'][$j]."' />"."<label for='".$radiocountc. "' title='".$_SESSION['items'][$j]."'>".$_SESSION['items'][$j]."</label></div></td>
</tr>";
}
}
echo "</table>";
?>
<input name="ranking_submit" type="submit" value="Rank Them"  />
</form>
```

This produces the following form code (html) that allows for selection:

```
<form name="ranking_submit" action="" method="post">

<br><table><tbody><tr><td class="rright ratecell"><div class="big ccenter"><input id="41" type="radio" required="required" name="1" value="Ralph"><label for="41" title="Ralph">Ralph</label></div></td>
<td class="ccenter"> vs </td>
<td class="ratecell"><div class="big ccenter"><input id="81" type="radio" name="1" value="Cindy"><label for="81" title="Cindy">Cindy</label></div></td>

</tr><tr><td class="rright ratecell"><div class="big ccenter"><input id="42" type="radio" required="required" name="2" value="Ralph"><label for="42" title="Ralph">Ralph</label></div></td>
<td class="ccenter"> vs </td>
<td class="ratecell"><div class="big ccenter"><input id="82" type="radio" name="2" value="Katie"><label for="82" title="Katie">Katie</label></div></td>

</tr><tr><td class="rright ratecell"><div class="big ccenter"><input id="43" type="radio" required="required" name="3" value="Cindy"><label for="43" title="Cindy">Cindy</label></div></td>
<td class="ccenter"> vs </td>
<td class="ratecell"><div class="big ccenter"><input id="83" type="radio" name="3" value="Katie"><label for="83" title="Katie">Katie</label></div></td>
</tr></tbody></table><input name="ranking_submit" type="submit" value="Rank Them">
</form>
```

I need to get the values from the radio selection, preferably with the key and value.  Later I'd like to count the number of selections per $_SESSION['items'] - in other words, find out how many times each item was selected.

I have tried this code to get the initial radio selection output, but it does not seem to work:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["ranking_submit"]) && !empty($_POST["ranking_submit"]))  { 
foreach($_POST['radiocountb'] as $value){
    echo "My values here"."</b>";
    echo "<span>selected :<b> ".$value."</b></span>";
}
    }
?>
```

If I simply echo the last $radiocountb then I get the correct latest count:

```
echo $radiocountb ."<br>";
```

Produces the latest count: 3 for three radio choices.

Please help - how can I obtain a list of the $_SESSION['items'] with an appropriate count on how many times they were each selected via radio choices?

Thank you very much for your help and consideration.

Comment: I don't see anyting with name `radiocountb` on your form. Do __you__ see?

Comment: in response to @u_mulder 's comment, you're doing `name='". $radiocountb ."'` on your form, but `$radiocountb` is a number, not text. So essentially you're doing `name='4'` instead of `name='radiocountb'`. Not sure how intentional this is but it seems suspicious. So `$_POST['radiocountb']` will be NULL instead of the value you're expecting because there's no input with the name "radiocountb".

Comment: you could also do something like `name="radiocountb[41]" value="Ralph` or `name="radiocountb[81]" value="Cindy"`, and then in PHP you can get `$_POST['radiocountb']` and it will return an array like `array(41 => 'Ralph', 81 => 'Cindy')`

Comment: The $radiocountb variable was a counter because the radio buttons are dynamically created by the previous array. I need to have a unique name per radio pair, so I thought the $radiocountb would work. 
So above instead of using $radiocountb I will try to use 

name='"radio. $radiocountb ."'"  - would that then make it a string?
thank you for your help.

Comment: I will try WOUNDEDStevenJones comment - I will try and get back to the group - it makes sense to me, but need time to try it.
Thank you very much for your help and I will let you know progress..

Comment: Thank you for your help! WOUNDEDStevenJones solution worked like a charm.This is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone's benfit, I am posting the ANSWER to the question, using the suggestion from WOUNDEDStevenJones:

I changed:

```
name='". $radiocountb ."'
```

To:

```
name='radiocountb[". $radiocountb ."]'
```

as follows:

```
<form name="ranking_submit" action="" method="post">
<?php
echo "<br>";
// compare each array item with each other - one time
$radiocounta = 40;
$radiocountb = 0;
$radiocountc = 80;

$sizeZ=count($_SESSION['items']);
echo "<table>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $sizeZ-1; $i++) 
{
    $radiocountb += 1;
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < $sizeZ; $j++) 
    {
    $radiocounta += 1;
    $radiocountc += 1;
    $radiocountb += 1;
echo "<tr><td class='rright ratecell'><div class='big ccenter'>"."<input id='".$radiocounta . "' type='radio' required='required' 
name='radiocountb[". $radiocountb ."]' value= '".$_SESSION['items'][$i]."' />"."<label for='".$radiocounta. "' title='".$_SESSION['items'][$i]."'>".$_SESSION['items'][$i]."</label></div></td>
<td class='ccenter'>"." vs "."</td>
<td class='ratecell'><div class='big ccenter'>"."<input id='".$radiocountc . "' type='radio' name='radiocountb[". $radiocountb ."]' value= '".$_SESSION['items'][$j]."' />"."<label for='".$radiocountc. "' title='".$_SESSION['items'][$j]."'>".$_SESSION['items'][$j]."</label></div></td>
</tr>";
    }
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
<input name="ranking_submit" type="submit" value="Rank Them"  />
</form>
```

That changed the radio array naming method.

Then, to get the radio values, I used the following:

```
<?php
 $selections= array();
    if (isset($_POST['radiocountb'])) {
foreach($_POST['radiocountb'] as $key=>$value){
        echo "<span>selected :<b> ".$key." ".$value."</b></span>"."<br />";
        $selections[] = $value;
   }
        }
?>
```

This did the trick.
Thank you WOUNDED StevenJones for your helpful comment that led to the solution.